# Organize a spinner shown in a listview

Tags: android, listview, spinner

How can I organize a spinner alphabetically that has its fields in a listView without manually changing the field data?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand the question, but here goes.

You can populate the spinner in a similar way that you populate the ListView.  That is by using an Adapter.   When  you create the adapter that you're using for the ListView, make one that you'll use for the spinner.

The type of adapter you use will be based on where the information you're using is coming from.

Does this help?

Comment: no :-( thnk's for your answer.:-)

the content of my spinner are created by a listView. I didn't have find how rank spinner or listview

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  You can try using a AlphabetIndexer to alphabetize the ListView.  Hope that helps